# Jquery code not working inside lightning:tabset

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am working on building a infinite scroll/lazy loading functionality on my custom table. I found the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery) to detect the the scroll has reached to end :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#flux').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            alert('end reached');
        }
    })
});
```

Below is my component custom table code :

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Jquery3_4_0}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" /> 
<div class="testflux" id="flux" >
    <table class="slds-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.appsInOppList}" var="wrapObj">
                <c:AppsInOutAccountRowComponent oppList="{!wrapObj.oppList}" />
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller.js

```
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("documentReady");
            $('#flux').on('scroll', function() {
                if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                    alert('end reached');
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

css

```
.THIS .testflux{height:150px;overflow:auto;}
```

The Jquery code is working fine on doinit. The same jquery code is not working(alert not firing) when table used inside **lightning:tabset** . Below is the code :

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Jquery3_4_0}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
<lightning:tabset>
    <lightning:tab label="Tab1" id="1">
        <div class="testflux" id="flux">
            <table class="slds-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Created Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.appsInOppList}" var="wrapObj">
                        <c:AppsInOutAccountRowComponent oppList="{!wrapObj.oppList}" />
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </lightning:tab>
    <lightning:tab label="Tab2" id="2">
    </lightning:tab>
</lightning:tabset>
```

Not able to figure out the issue.